# Adding script in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel but I'm getting to grips with it.

At the moment there a partial blade that just includes scripts from the public assets folder, like below.

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}}"></script>  
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/library/slick/slick.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/library/slick/slick-init.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/library/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/library/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/library/tinymce/tinymce-settings.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/isotope-docs.min.js')}}"></script> <!-- JQuery and Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/grid.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/lfm.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendor/laravel-filemanager/js/lfm.js')}}"></script>
```

I feel like this is a bit messy and far from optimal.

I did some poking around in `resources/assets/js` and saw that by default Laravel uses `bootstrap.js` and then grabs this in `app.js`. Also the items in `bootstrap.js` seem to be grabbed directly from the `node_modules` folder.

Is it better practice to instead include all the JavaScript libraries in `bootstrap.js`?

If so, could I install all these libraries via NPM and somehow include them in the `bootstrap.js` file? At least the ones that are available via npm.

Then in my footer I could just include `app.js` instead of my individual scripts.

Comment: It might be better but keep in mind some 3rd party libraries simply can't be included that way. Rule of thumb, if you can install it using NPM then you can use it in app.js and then "compile" it using mix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel `mix` to concatenate, minify/uglify your JS, style assets.

> [Laravel mix documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix)

Comment: I've had a brief look through the docs previously but is it just a case of using Mix to copy folders to the public directory?

Comment: @JesseOrange - it allows you to combine you JS files into 1 file - that way your blade files need to only include 1 JS file.